# Groupby for clusters generation

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how I can group by date/time the following dataset:

```
     T                   Text
75  -1 days +20:07:00   orms
34  -1 days +22:07:00   rinanews
23  00:07:00            wrwfs
19  02:07:00            wwf 
28  03:07:00            geological
... ... ...
58  15:07:00            chrew
42  15:07:00            Liverpool 
27  15:07:00            seafood
```

The above list is only sorted by date. What I would like to is to group these factors by date and plot the clusters generated by this grouping.

Any tips on how I could do it?

I have tried as `df2.groupby(['T', 'Text'])`. but it does not show anything.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: My fault. Yes, I was poorly clear about the topic. I wanted to group by date texts, to have all the text value having 15:07 (so chrew, Liverpool and seafood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are attempting to do, but `.groupby()` returns an object (not a dataframe). This object contains a list of tuples each containing `(tuple_of_group_labels, list_of_group_indexes)`, so with the line you used, the first element of each tuple would be itself a tuple containing all unique combinations of `T` and `Text`, and the second element would be a list containing the indexes for the rows that belong to each group.

For example, the last item in your `groupby object` would be a tuple containing a tuple and a list `((15:07:00, 'seafood'), [27, ])`

### Where to go from here?

It all depends on what you want to do with each group. Possible options are:

- `.aggregate()`: sum, mean, size/count, max, min, and many more
- `.apply()`: more advanced, but you can apply virtually any function that is not already vectorized and can take a dataframe/series as an input and return either a dataframe/series of the same shape or an aggregated scalar
- `.transform()`: similar to aggregate but it will broadcast the returned value to the same shape as self (e.g. if you have a column with a value and want to add a column with the the mean for each group)

You can read more in the [user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)

### My guess of what you need

Try

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['T', 'Text']).size()
```